# Using Tornado to serve xml formatted with xsl

Tags: javascript, python, xml, xslt, tornado

I am trying to have tornado serve up an xml file and transform it using xsl.

I'm using:

`xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);` and `xmlhttp.send();` in javascript/html

`self.render("cd_catalog.xml")` in Python

`document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` in javascript/html.

The results are a non-formatted xml file.

Why doesn't the xsl transform the xml? What am I missing?

Python:

```
import os
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            self.render("index.html")
class Test(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            self.render("cd_catalog.xml")

def main():
    application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/Test", Test),
    ])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5003))
    http_server.listen(port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

JS/HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function loadXMLDoc(url)
    {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="myDiv"><h2>get list of presidents</h2></div>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc('/Test')">OK</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cd_catalog.xsl"?>
    <catalog>
      <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
      </cd>
    .
    .
    </catalog>
```

XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
      <body>
      <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
      <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>Artist</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tornado didn't apply the XSL because you didn't ask it to. Instead, by using `RequestHandler.render()`, you asked Tornado to render the file as a Tornado template and send the result to the browser. Instead, you should explicitly run the file through an XSL processor of your choice, and then use `RequestHandler.write()` to send the result to the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes a lot of sense. Would you recommend using lxml to transform the xml in python?

Comment: I've never worked with XSL so I don't have any recommendations here.

Answer (score 0):

It works, thanks.  Here's an example:

```
    import os
    import tornado.httpserver
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.web
    import lxml.etree as ET

    class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
            def get(self):
                    self.render("index.html")
    class Test(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
            def get(self):
                    dom = ET.parse("cd_catalog.xml")
                    xslt = ET.parse("cd_catalog.xsl")
                    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
                    newdom = transform(dom)
                    self.write(ET.tostring(newdom, pretty_print=True))

    def main():
            application = tornado.web.Application([
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/Test", Test),
            ])
            http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
            port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5003))
            http_server.listen(port)
            tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```